# What is a colloquial and figurative expression for the pieces of luggage you carry when travelling light

Tags: expressions, colloquialisms, phrase-requests, figurative

I am looking for a figurative or graphic expression to describe the minimal luggage content, fast to pack, or that you always have with you, without which you would feel less safe when travelling. The  expression should be concise too.

When I take a plane, and since luggage in the  cargo area can get lost, I generally have a toothbrush and underwear. With those, I am not afraid of spending an unplanned night in an hotel in a unknown town.

I would say in my language that I have my "pants and brush", as a short for "a second pair of underpants, socks and a toothbrush", but this does not seem colloquial in English.

In other words, is there a colloquial figurative expression for what one carries when travelling light?

Comment: I have heard the expression "grab-bag" used to describe a small piece of luggage, often kept pre-packed and near the door of one's house so that one may travel suddenly and lightly. That may be appropriate here.

Comment: The prepacked thing in the front closet or car trunk is often called a "Bug-out Bag". That's usually for making a quick escape. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bug-out_bag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Ditty bag**.

The quotes below are both from Michael Quinion's World Wide Words blog.

> Ditty bag comes from the days of sailing ships: On each side of the
>   berth-deck, termed “the wings,” are racks for the accommodation of
>   canvass bags; each man has one in which he keeps his clothes, and a
>   little bag or reticule called “a ditty bag,” containing all the
>   implements of his housewifery, such as thimble, needles, tapes,
>   thread, &c, for you must know that every genuine seaman is always his
>   own tailor, hatter, and very frequently his own shoemaker. The Journal
>   of Belles Lettres, Philadelphia, 1833.

And later in the same article -

> Ditty bag remained a term exclusively of the sea until the twentieth
>   century. Landlubbers took it up and used it for any small cloth
>   container for items of kit or miscellaneous stuff. It’s almost
>   completely defunct in the UK but survives widely in north America in
>   all sorts of situations. So it’s unsurprising that you have found it
>   in the film business.

http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-dit2.htm

Comment: Lot of marine words lost in the sea. +1 for reviving this one

Comment: It's a golden flotsam

Answer (score 2):

To ***[travel light](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/travel+light)***:

> - to bring very few things with you when you go on a trip.
>
>   - *My new car has lots of cargo space, which is great for people like me who don't travel light.*

(Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms)

also the colloquial expression:

***[No-bags travel](https://ricasrucksack.com/no-bag-travel/)***

Comment: Thannk you. I probably should have put this one in the OP, since I am looking for something more figurative or visual.

Comment: @LaurentDuval I think josh's answer encompasses what you're asking for but if you want something else, please be specific. Do you mean an expression that means to carry the most vital stuff for travel that also happens to be tiny or only tiny stuff and vitals?

Comment: @vickyace I hope I rephrased the question in a more specific manner

Answer (score 2):

You are asking for the collective term for your "pants and brush".

Try *travel essentials*.

> **Essentials** *noun*
>   1 A thing that is absolutely necessary: *we only had the bare essentials in the way of equipment*
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/essential?q=essentials#essential__8)

Here's a [pinterest page](https://au.pinterest.com/explore/travel-essentials/) of *travel essentials*.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with **Personal effects**

From M-W:

> privately owned items (as clothing and jewelry) normally worn or carried on the person

Example:

> When my baggage was lost in transit, all I was left with was my
>   personal effects